# Install an external plugin from within the current plugin?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to install an additional plugin, and all I have is the slug name of the plugin under api.wordpress.org.
I've figured out that one could get the zip file's path (download_link) when going to http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/plugin-slug

What would be the rest? I wouldn't want to do the entire unzipping if there's a built-in function in WP that does that...?

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: I have some related plugins that can work with my plugin, and  I'd like to install them (on user confirmation only of course).

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation ?

Comment: TGM-Plugin-Activation is the right way to go - I've used it before for this exact purpose.

Comment: I ended up writing my own plugin as a result - [WP Plugin Packer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-plugin-packer/)

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117459/plugin-to-install-a-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution should do the job for you.

http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

The solution is meant for theme developers to package to download, automatically install and activate multiple plugins that are either packaged with a theme, downloaded from the WordPress Plugin Repository or downloaded elsewhere on the internet (perhaps a private repository.

The code of the solution can be used to accomplish what you are trying to achieve. The code is also available on GitHub at:

https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

In addition with Pali Madra's answer, this is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
> require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.